# Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ' AnyObject?!'

Tags: json, swift, nsmutablearray, immutablearray

I did some search but still cannot figure out how to solve the error.
Basically I am reading booklist from Json file and then update it. The reading part is fine but error ("Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ' AnyObject?!'") happens when trying to update.

```
var url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Book", withExtension: "json")

var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

var booklist = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSMutableArray


for boo in booklist {
            if (boo["name"]  as! String) == "BookB" {
                print (boo["isRead"]) //see Console Output
                boo["isRead"] = "true"  //this gets error "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ' AnyObject?!'"
            }
```

The Json file Book.json is as below:

```
[
{"name":"BookA","auth":"AAA","isRead":"false",},
{"name":"BookB","auth":"BBB","isRead":"false",},
{"name":"BookC","auth":"CCC","isRead":"false",},
]
```

The booklist has expected values, see Console output:

```
(
        {
        name = BookA;
        auth = AAA;
        isRead = false;
    },
        {
        name = BookB;
        auth = BBB;
        isRead = false; 
    },
       {
        name = BookC;
        auth = CCC;
        isRead = false;
    }
)
```

and for `print (boo["isRead"])`, the console result is `Optional(false)`, which is correct.

Booklist is already a NSMutableArray, and I also tried to change as

```
var booklist = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
```

but it does not help.

Also referred to [Swift: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject?!'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093692/swift-cannot-assign-to-immutable-expression-of-type-anyobject), changing to below also get the same error:

```
var mutableObjects = booklist
for var boo in mutableObjects {
            if (boo["name"]  as! String) == "BookB" {
                print (boo["isRead"]) //see Console Output
                boo["isRead"] = "true"  //this gets error "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ' AnyObject?!'"
            }
```

Could anyone advise how to update the isRead in booklist for BookB in this case. Or even better how to update the Book.json file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject?!'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093692/swift-cannot-assign-to-immutable-expression-of-type-anyobject)

Comment: the solution in that question does not work for me...

Comment: You're right. I posted a working answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you hit this error twice:

1. in the `for` loop, which you correctly edited
2. because the compiler doesn't know the type of `boo` (it's just an element of an `NSMutableArray`)

To fix this you could write:

```
for var boo in mutableObjects {
    if var theBoo = boo as? NSMutableDictionary {
        if (theBoo["name"]  as! String) == "BookB" {
            print (theBoo["isRead"]) //see Console Output
            theBoo["isRead"] = "true"  //this gets error "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ' AnyObject?!'"
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you give the compiler a hint about the type of `boo` with:

```
    guard let theBoos = mutableObjects as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] else {
        return
    }

    for var theBoo in theBoos {
        if (theBoo["name"]  as! String) == "BookB" {
            print (theBoo["isRead"]) //see Console Output
            theBoo["isRead"] = "true"  //this gets error "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ' AnyObject?!'"
        }
    }
```